# Не получается встроить функцию смены цвета

Tags: javascript, canvas

Подскажите пожалуйста, что в данном случае не так

```
window.onload = function() { 
    setTimeout("changeColor()", 300);     
}
```

Не принимает браузер. Заранее спасибо

```js
const SF_SIZE = 1;
const SF_COUNT = 1000;
const WIND = 0.7;

var r = 255;
var g = 255;
var b = 255;

var canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas"),
  context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  sfArr = [];

context.lineWidth = SF_SIZE;

for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {
  sfArr.push({
    x: randomInt(-canvas.width * WIND, canvas.width - 1),
    y: randomInt(0, canvas.height - 1)
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {
  snowflake(sfArr[i].x, sfArr[i].y);
}


function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function snowflake(squarePosition_x, squarePosition_y) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(squarePosition_x, squarePosition_y);
  context.lineTo(squarePosition_x + context.lineWidth, squarePosition_y + context.lineWidth);
  context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
  context.stroke();
}

function changeColor() {
  if (r == 255 && g == 255 && b == 255) {
    r = 10;
    g = 10;
    b = 10;
  } else {
    r = 255;
    g = 255;
    b = 255;
  }
  setTimeout("changeColor()", 100);
}

window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout("changeColor()", 300);
}
```

```css
#drawingCanvas {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90vw;
  background-color: #447;
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect -->

<canvas id="drawingCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: попробуйте написать вот так: `setTimeout(changeColor, 300)` без кавычек и скобок

Comment: У меня всё работает. Ну, то есть, ничего не происходит, но если console.log вставить в chagneColor - то видно, что оно вызывается.
Какой у вас браузер?

Answer (score 1):

Вызывается `changeColor()`.

```js
const SF_SIZE = 1;
const SF_COUNT = 1000;
const WIND = 0.7;

var r = 255;
var g = 255;
var b = 255;

var canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas"),
  context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  sfArr = [];

context.lineWidth = SF_SIZE;

for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {
  sfArr.push({
    x: randomInt(-canvas.width * WIND, canvas.width - 1),
    y: randomInt(0, canvas.height - 1)
  });
}

function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function snowflake(squarePosition_x, squarePosition_y) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(squarePosition_x, squarePosition_y);
  context.lineTo(squarePosition_x + context.lineWidth, squarePosition_y + context.lineWidth);
  context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
  context.stroke();
}

function changeSnow() {
  for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {
    snowflake(sfArr[i].x, sfArr[i].y);
  }
}

function changeColor() {
  if (r == 255 && g == 255 && b == 255) {
    r = 10;
    g = 10;
    b = 10;
  } else {
    r = 255;
    g = 255;
    b = 255;
  }
  setTimeout("changeColor()", 1000);
  changeSnow();
}

window.onload = function() {
  changeSnow();
  setTimeout("changeColor()", 300);
}
```

```css
#drawingCanvas {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90vw;
  background-color: #447;
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect -->

<canvas id="drawingCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Если смена цвета вызывается, почему визуально не видно, что цвет точек меняется с белого (255, 255, 255) на почти черный  (0, 0 , 10)?

Comment: @Наташа Потому что функция вызывается, но работает не так, как вам нужно, логично же.

Comment: @Наташа сейчас посмотрите, это то чего вы добивались?

Comment: @Puvvl да, огромное спасибо, вижу правки =)